# Can I set up Canon 6D Auto Exposure Bracketing (AEB) to take more than 3 shots?

Tags: canon, hdr, bracketing, canon-6d

The AEB range on a 6D is  -3 to +3 EV.  I normally set up my my AEB to take 3 shots at -2,0,+2 or -2.5,0,+2.5.  I used the results for exposure "safety", to create an HDR if candidate scene is suitable, or creative work with over and under exposed frames.

I sometimes use a cable release and a timer for long exposures and I noticed that when I use 5 - 7 exposures created in this way and these have more less increment amount of exposure time to create an HDR the result is better and easier to work with.

**Can I set up my 6D to take 5 or more auto bracketed exposures at say -3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3 EV?**

Note: I am too afraid to install magic lantern on my 6D but am willing to experiment with it on my 60D if this is something that's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. Refer pg 305 of the standard English manual.

Custom function C.Fn I-5 'Number of bracketed shots'
0: 3 shots (default)
1: 2 shots
2: 5 shots
3: 7 shots

FYI: C.Fn I-4 lets you change the sequence of brackets shots - this could be useful when creating HDR shots as the order of the photos is from lowest to highest exposure value.
0: 0 - + (default)
1: - 0 +
2: + 0 -